# Convergence of series (factorial)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I cant think of a way to approach

$$\sum_n\frac{1}{n\ln(n!)}$$

I tried Cauchy condensation test, but then i don't know how to deal with

$$\frac{1}{\ln((2^n)!)}$$

Any hints are welcome, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots\cdot n\ge 1\cdot 2\cdots\cdot 2=2^{n-1}$ so:

$$\frac{1}{n\ln(n!)}\le\frac{1}{n\ln(2^{n-1})}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)\ln 2}$$

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting it...

Comment: Comparison test with $\sum\frac{1}{n(n-1)\ln 2}$ which then you can compare to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: ye sorry i get that,

Comment: what i did not get is how we ended up to having  1/n(n-1)ln2

Comment: Considering (2^n)!= (2^(n-1))(2^n)!

Comment: Just compare the factorial $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n$ with the product of $n$ terms where we replaced anything greater than $2$ by $2$: $1\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdots 2$ (which has $n-1$ twos). It is very crude but it works.

Comment: Gosh sorry bro you're right, it was way easier than i thought

Comment: Thanks for your time bro, have a good day!